# Shopify Public App - How To Get Key, Token & Url

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am totally new to Shopify Public App development and I will need your help to understand it a bit better.

For a client, I need to build a Shopify Public App that will be used by several Merchants.

This application will have to access the Merchants' store via the Admin API.

If my understanding is correct, in order to access one specific Merchant's store via the Admin API, I need to have 3 pieces of information from that Merchant's store: the Public API Key, Token and URL.

Now, my question:
When the Shopify Public App is installed by a Merchant, how does my app get these 3 pieces of information (specific to that particular merchant) ?
Is there any "magic" trick?  Does the Merchant need to input this info? ...

In advance, many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

For those who might be interested, I finally found the link to the information.
[Shopify - Getting started with OAuth](https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

Each merchant will need to install your app. In the installation phase shopify will pass, as an argument, the access token, that is a token that you will need, to use the Admin API.

If we're talking about an embedded app is expected that every request made is authenticated.

Depending on which kind of app you want to create (embedded or not) and language you may want to use, using the Shopify Cli to create the first draft of the app is really reccommended. It will create the base to have an installable app. Here is the documentation https://shopify.dev/apps/getting-started/create

You need to install the Shopify Cli and then run

`shopify app create (node | ruby | php)`

depending on your language of choice.